# What is a cubical sphere?

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, polytopes

Roughly, a cubical complex is like a simplicial complex except all the pieces glued together are combinatorial cubes of various dimensions.
A cubical sphere is a cubical complex that is homeomorphic to a sphere.
I have encountered papers that distinguish between cubical spheres and cubical polytopes,
but I do not understand the distinction.  Is there a distinction already in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
If so, could anyone provide an example?
A reference to clear definitions would suffice as well. Thanks!

My understanding is that, say, the rhombic triacontahedron is both a cubical polytope and a cubical sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

          
[image: Rhombic triacontahedron]

          <sub>[Image from Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron)</sub>

Comment: Nice image. XD +1

Comment: I think the distinction is that you don't allow "holes" in a cubical sphere. So, for example (I hope I make myself clear): take nine dice and arrange them as a $3 \times 3$-square. Remove the one in the middle. The surface of this certainly gives you a cubical complex that doesn't deserve the name sphere, as it is homeomorphic to a torus.

Comment: @Theo: So is your torus then classified as a cubical polytope?

Comment: I would say so. The square faces can be glued to a polytope along their edges. (A polytope doesn't include convexity assumptions, as far as I know).

Comment: How do you define "combinatorial cubes"?

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, yes, that is what confuses me. Normally the word _polytope_ would not include a torus, in any dimension.  But perhaps that is because "polytope" usually abbreviates "convex polytope."  To confuse matters further, there are the "cubical pseudomanifolds"...

Comment: On the other hand some googling reveals that e.g. [Ziegler](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/gmziegler/) uses cubical polytopes only for *convex* polytopes, and he certainly has more authority than I do... (I didn't see your last comment before posting).

Comment: @Michael: Good question! I think the meaning used for these cubical thingies might be both combinatorial (in terms of poset inclusion) and geometrical.  Concerning the latter, a face of a cubical polytope in $\mathbb{R}^3$ should both be a quadrilateral and planar.  Otherwise I think authors would precede the terms with the adjective "abstract."

Comment: So a combinatorial cube is something that has the same inclusions among its faces as the usual $n$-cube?

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment): Here are some thoughts on this circle of ideas though I am not sure what distinctions have been made with these terms in the literature. The diagram you show is a 3-polytope whose surface is built up of 2-dimensional combinatorial cubes, namely 4--gons. However, it is not clear that this 3-polytope or similar 3-polytopes including their interior points can be always be decomposed as 3-cubes that meet along faces. The note on this page which talks about combinatorial cubes: http://www.york.cuny.edu/~malk/tidbits/n-cube-tidbit.html  shows a diagram of as 4-cube but it also can be thought of a 3-cube whose interior has been cut up into other combinatorial 3-cubes. As regards the torus, there are some graphs which will not embed on a sphere but will embed on a torus. Now one can ask if one can embed in 3-space a surface (topologically a torus) with flat faces so that the vertex edge graph of this surface is the given graph. When this is possible it is common to call the resulting surface a toroidal polytope. The adjective toroidal overcomes the usage of polytope to be something convex.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, I think you are absolutely correct in focusing on building the 2-surface from glued 3-cubes, as opposed to just looking at the surface alone. (I think in my example it accidentally works out, because it is a zonotope...)

Comment: Joe: The dual of any 4-valent 3-polytope will have all of its faces 4-gons but I would be surprised if all of these 3-polytopes can be decomposed into 3-cubes.

Comment: Perhaps this thesis might be of interest:  http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=146088

Comment: Thanks, Joe, I will look at it! (Sorry for not revisiting this in so long...)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the cubical polytopes are convex - otherwise it's easy to come up with counterexamples - say cubulated tori.

In this case the distinction can be framed as follows. Say you have a cubical convex polytope - this is homeomorphic to a ball so its boundary always gives you a cubical sphere. So the set of cubical polytopes are contained in the set of cubical spheres (in the sense of combinatorial equivalence of their face lattice). The more interesting question is whether each cubical sphere is combinatorially equivalent to the boundary of a convex cubical polytope.

In three dimensions (or equivalently for $2$-spheres) cubical polytopes and cubical spheres coincide. Given any cubical $2$-sphere, its $1$-skeleton is a 3-connected planar graph so we can use Steinitz's Theorem to construct a polytope with the same combinatorial type.

Things get trickier in higher dimensions. I do not know of an explicit example of a non-polytopal $3$-sphere in the *cubical* case but the *simplicial* case has been studied extensively. There are many examples of simplicial $3$-spheres that are not combinatorially equivalent to the boundary of any $4$ simplicial polytope. The typical construction uses a knot on $3$ edges inside the simplicial sphere. If the knot is non-trivial the corresponding sphere will be non-shellable and thus not polytopal since every polytope is shellable. See Theorem 1 and 2  [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309149.pdf). In the same paper Lutz gives a small example of a non-polytopal sphere on $13$ vertices. I think one could use the same ideas starting from Furch's knotted [cube](http://infoshako.sk.tsukuba.ac.jp/~hachi/math/library/knot_eng.html) to get a non-shellable cubical 3-sphere.